# Sharepoint Designer - is there a way to calculate a date difference in a workflow?

Tags: sharepoint, date, workflow, sharepoint-designer, datediff

Maybe I'm just crazy... So, with SPD I can add any time unit to a date and put that into a variable, but I can't seem to find anything that will let me calculate the difference between two dates.  "Do Calculation" only lets me pick from numeric values.  Am I missing something here? Seems like something which should be obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Date comparison is not available "out of the box", but there are some workarounds.

Maybe this article: [How to perform date calculations and construct dynamic strings in a SharePoint Designer workflow](http://www.documentmanagementworkflowinfo.com/sample-sharepoint-workflows/date-calculations-construct-dynamic-strings-sharepoint-designer-workflows.htm) provides the answer?

Some more related information here: [Modifying Date Formats in SharePoint Designer Workflows](http://blogs.3sharp.com/davidg/archive/2009/01/28/5030.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function **DATEDIF** of SharePoint lists to set a column value and then use it in workflows. I am sure, [this](http://blogs.sharepointace.com/post/SharePoint-List-Calculated-Column-Calculate-Business-Days.aspx) will help someone out there -

Answer (score 0):

As of SharePoint 2013 you can use "Find Interval Between Dates" action.

> ```
> Find Interval Between Dates
> Calculates the time interval in minutes, hours, or days between two dates and stores the output in a variable.
> ```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164026.aspx

Answer (score -1):

String and date manipulation as well as calculations are a pain in SharePoint Designer workflows. The links Colin mentioned are good, but you may also want to consider embedding C# or vb.net code directly into your SharePoint Designer Workflow (Without the need for Visual Studio).

I wrote a component that allows you to do this and blogged about it at the following URL:

http://www.muhimbi.com/blog/2009/12/embed-c-or-vb-code-directly-in.html